# How do universities validate race declarations?

Tags: graduate-admissions, diversity

In the US, competition  for admission to  elite universities (whether for an PhD, MA, BA, or even for a position as a professor) is fierce. Race is a more or less official consideration in admissions.

How do universities check racial declarations?  If a person does not look a given race in an interview, does a staffer makes a note? I don't think they do that, and anyway, some racial categories have no visible difference.

[Some reports](https://www.insidehighered.com/admissions/article/2021/10/25/survey-asks-if-applicants-are-truthful-about-race) have said that applicants do lie, but I am primarily interested in how universities validate such declarations (at all levels: for a graduate or undergraduate degree, or a job). And if they don't, given the ferocity of the competition and the lack of validation, why don't *more* applicants make something up?

Comment: I have a feeling they don't validate race declarations, and rely on the fact that most people will be honest.

Comment: Esther,thank you. Is there such a thing as honest or dishonest when these categories are a matter of self-identification?

Comment: @JoshuaFox Self-identification isn't synonymous with arbitrary, but it means the government isn't defining categories like "if you're 1/16 Black (whatever *that* means) you count as Black", as has been done in past times.

Comment: @BryanKrause: I'm not sure I follow the claim that "Self-identification isn't synonymous with arbitrary". Suppose that (i) I identify my "race" in some way, and (2) most others disagree with me. What's the consequence? If (2) does not matter, then self-identification is indeed just arbitrary. But if (2) does matter, then it's not mere "self"-identification.

Comment: @JochenGlueck I don't mean to use arbitrary in a mathematical sense where 'arbitrary' is opposite to 'specified', and can come with many implied or explicit constraints.

Comment: @JochenGlueck do you actually consider yourself that race, or do you just write it on the form for laughs?

Comment: @JoshuaFox "Honest" usually refers to concordance with personal beliefs/knowledge, versus with some absolute truth. One can give an honest opinion, despite opinions being by definition a matter of self-identification. "Dishonest" conveys an intent to deliberately mislead (a person stating something as true despite not actually believing it's true), which is distinct from unintentionally stating a falsehood (e.g. an "honest mistake").

Comment: @R.M.: Your comment reminds me of the following question I have (since this whole "race thing" in the US continues to be quite baffling for me): What if someone honestly does not identify with any race (for instance because they don't believe in the concept "race"): Can one leave this field in an application form blank, or maybe write down something generic such as "human"?

Comment: @JochenGlueck I also have not lived in the US for decades, but I think the forms usually allow one to refuse to answer.

Comment: @JoshuaFox: Thanks for your comment! That's good to know.

Comment: @JochenGlueck My assumption is that those who refuse to answer are categorized into the  least-benefited category.

Answer (score 12):

> How do universities check racial declarations?

They don’t.

> And if they don't, given the ferocity of the competition and the lack of validation, why don't more applicants make something up?

“More applicants” compared to what? If you mean compared to the rate of dishonesty claimed in the report you linked to, it seems already quite high to me personally, so I don’t know why you’d expect an even higher rate. In any case, that report measures the rate of white applicants who *admit* in a survey to claiming a false racial classification - that is, it is measuring the percentage of “honest liars”, if you will. It’s possible that there are yet more dishonest people who will not admit to such behavior even in an anonymous survey.

It’s also possible that the numbers in the report are unreliable for other reasons, and of course it’s possible that your view of humanity is more jaded than it deserves to be. Finally, perhaps some people don’t lie not because they are honest but because they are fearful of future negative repercussions if they do lie (as described in @BryanKrause’s answer). In other words, the negative stigma associated with claiming a false racial identity, and social taboo against such behavior, is what provides the negative incentive discouraging such behavior (whether that’s effective or not), rather than any enforcement mechanism implemented by universities themselves.

Comment: Thank you. It would seem  that many peoples' conscience would easily stretch to "identifying as" some group if it gives them a tiny edge. They can say to themselves that they are African American because all humans' ancestry stretches back to Africa. (Whether or not that's nonsense, it might suffice to some as a conscience-salving excuse.) Yet I sense (maybe I'm wrong) that far fewer applicants cheat this way than  other ways -- even though cheating on exams and the tricks used in "Varsity Blues" are are to some extent policed and this one, not at all.

Comment: @JoshuaFox there are claims that cheating and unethical behavior by college applicants and even their parents are indeed widespread, see [here](https://www.propublica.org/article/university-of-illinois-financial-aid-fafsa-parents-guardianship-children-students) and [here](https://www.forbes.com/sites/nickmorrison/2021/07/15/its-not-just-the-super-rich-who-cheat-to-get-their-child-into-college/?sh=667e6d751d09). Why more of it does not take the form of lying about one's race (or whether that's actually the case), I don't think anyone knows with certainty.

Comment: ... @JoshuaFox However, an important piece of context that seems relevant is that in the US, race is an _extremely_ sensitive and loaded issue, in a way that might be difficult to appreciate for someone who doesn't live here. Lying about one's race in such a cultural context would be seen as really a rather taboo thing to do for most normal people, including even many who might be willing to resort to other types of dishonest measures to get into a good college.

Comment: That is a good hypothesis. However, half the US is not on the side that strongly holds  the same set of taboos characteristic of elite colleges. Some small fraction is indeed on the other side. Even though they think that way, many want the imprimatur  of an elite university. So I would expect enhouh of these to be willing to write down the acceptance-maximizing value in their applications, at least to the same extent that they are willing to cheat on tests. And by "enough", I mean enough that unis would be forced to try to validate these answers.

Comment: @JoshuaFox it’s an empirical fact that universities don’t validate claims about people’s race. The fact that this is contrary to your expectations is neither here nor there.

Comment: I can't back this up, but I think that in the case of Native American or Native Hawaiian, you need to be registered with a tribe, at least for certain kinds of preferences.

Answer (score 8):

Race in the US is a matter of self-identification. I am not aware of any university program to validate racial identification.

Quoting from the [article you reference](https://www.insidehighered.com/admissions/article/2021/10/25/survey-asks-if-applicants-are-truthful-about-race):

> Admissions experts have varying views of the survey. Most said that colleges do not routinely attempt to verify applicants’ answers on what race or ethnicity they are. Some doubted that such a large percentage are lying. And they said the answers point to misperceptions about the admissions process. But they agreed that lying is a problem.

there seems to be a mix of opinions on the situation.

There of course have been some high-profile cases in the media where people have reached a social status of public interest (for example, elected officials) and have been found to have lied or misled about their racial or ethnic background, and this has cost them in the court of public opinion.

Perhaps it's not something people lie about often because, despite the implication in your question that lying about race gives an advantage, maybe that advantage isn't actually perceived to be that large or exist at all, and that applicants who are actually filling out their applications (as opposed to a survey about their application) are more cautious about what it means to lie: will they face punishment? will they face discrimination based on the race they claim?

> Race is a more or less official consideration in admissions

I assume you refer to [affirmative action](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Affirmative_action), but the statement is certainly not universally true. Racial quotas are not legal in the US, and at most race is a minor contributor in a wholistic admissions process.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/140325/discussion-on-answer-by-bryan-krause-how-do-universities-validate-race-declarati).

Answer (score 0):

As others answered, there's not really a practical way for colleges to verify race.

> why don't more applicants make something up?

Because if too many people do it, it becomes an ineffective strategy. If the admissions office gives preferential treatment to X, and everyone is X, then they're preferring everyone, which means they're not preferring anyone.

Comment: That doesn't make sense. Even if everyone else is (or claims to be) X, so being (or claiming to be) X doesn't put you at an advantage, it's still effective because it avoids being at a disadvantage.

Comment: That's the "zero-sum game" argument against affirmative action, which I don't believe.

Comment: @Barmar What EspeciallyLime pointed out is called [strategic dominance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strategic_dominance), which has nothing to do with whether the underlying game is [zero-sum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero-sum_game).

Comment: @Barmar no, it's not. In fact it's *your* claim (everyone being preferred is the same as no-one being preferred) that assumes a zero-sum game. If it's not zero-sum then the fact that others are gaining from being X doesn't stop you gaining from being X too.

Comment: Isn't that the essence of the current SCOTUS cases about affirmative action? The plaintiffs claim that affirmative action in favor of Blacks disadvantages Asians and Whites -- if someone wins, someone else loses.